How do I set up GitLab pipelines for a mono repo where pipelines only trigger on file changes?
My repo currently looks something like this
.
├── a/
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── .gitlab-ci.yml
│   └── README.md
├── b/
│   ├── script.sh
│   └── README.md
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
└── README.md

Project a has a pipeline with jobs to run but project b doesn't. Note in the future I might have other projects with pipelines. I want the pipelines in each respective project to only trigger when files change in that project folder. I have some jobs I want to run on merge request pipelines and branch pipelines, maybe others in the future.
My parent .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this
stages:
  - projects

project_a:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: a/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
      - a/*

And my a/.gitlab-ci.yml looks something like:
stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo hello
  rules:
    - when: on_success

The reason I have the when: on_success in the child pipeline is that I read that by default pipelines don't run on merge requests and adding a rule like that will "fix that". I don't know if that's the best solution but it seems to work for merge requests after adding it
Anyway everything was working fine but upon making a change in the root README.md file, all pipelines were triggered.
I'm going to guess that my rule for file changes isn't working properly. Would like some help with setting this up

I think I figured out why... It's comparing changes to the branch I'm merging into so of course it will continue to detect changes as long as at least one file in project a is changed. To test this I added a compare_to to the parent trigger rules to compare to a previous commit
stages:
  - projects

project_a:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: a/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
          - a/*
        compare_to: abcd1234
      

I made a change outside project a and low and behold, the pipeline didn't run.
Major facepalm on my end
